# No module named 'psychopy' while using PyGaze

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the shooting_game package that comes with PyGaze. While running the code it asks me my name (Player name) and as soon as I enter it, an error pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-03fc3ba04ddb>", line 4, in <module>
    from pygaze import libtime

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygaze\libtime.py", line 
25, in <module>
    from pygaze._time.psychopytime import PsychoPyTime as Time

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\pygaze\_time\psychopytime.py", line 22, in <module>
    import psychopy.core

ImportError: No module named 'psychopy'
```

Before this problem arose, there were other modules which weren't working. As far as I remember I had copy pasted the pygaze script file (names of which are imported in the program) to the my path location. This worked as many modules could be imported and it even asked me for a playername input. The next thing though, is why I'm here.

```
import highscores
from constants import *

from pygaze import libtime
from pygaze.libscreen import Display, Screen
from pygaze.libinput import Keyboard
from pygaze.eyetracker import EyeTracker

import random
```

I expect it to track my eyeball movements and according to that provide me with a game to shoot at targets. It only asks me for the name initially and then breaks down saying module not found. For more on PyGaze and where to install, check: http://www.pygaze.org/

Edit: I did try pip install psychopy, but this was the result from cmd:
    `from setuptools.config import read_configuration 
    ImportError: No module named 'setuptools.config`

And then I tried pip install setuptools and turns out I already had it. Still this pops up.

Edit 2: Latest update, I followed the comments below and installed setuptools, but while installing I hit another roadblock. Check my comment(s) on this post from 12-02-19.

Comment: If a module is missing, you should properly install it. Did you try `pip install psychopy`?

Comment: I did that with a few other modules, but pip install psychopy says another module is missing. "
    from setuptools.config import read_configuration
    ImportError: No module named 'setuptools.config'
"
I tried pip install setuptools and it said requirement already satisfied. I had it already, yet..

Comment: Upgrade setuptools. python -m pip install -U setuptools

Comment: Did that @Atirag, it downloaded and installed but said this:
"  Found existing installation: setuptools 27.2.0
Cannot remove entries from nonexistent file c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\easy-install.pth" -- the last line in red

Comment: python -m pip install -U --ignore-installed setuptools

Comment: @Atirag Okay so that worked to move ahead with the process. Got setuptools and then tried installing psychopy (which was a long process), but in the end I got an error: "Installing collected packages: appdirs, pywin32, pypiwin32, pyqmix, PyQt5-sip, pyqt5, psychopy
  Found existing installation: pywin32 220
Cannot uninstall 'pywin32'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall."